# Htaccess - Validate if Cookie ISSET

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, redirect, cookies

How do I do the validation, that whenever a cookie isset. This user will be redirected to the given page.

This is what I currently have (which is redirecting the user, if there is NO cookie set, but I want the opposite):

```
RewriteEngine On
// Redirect user, if cookie EXISTS, and if not, ignore this whole code.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !_sTrxIT=(.*);? [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.google.com [R]
```

It would be a pleasure for me, if anyone had some suggestions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} _sTrxIT=[^;]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.google.com [L,R=302]
```

Comment: What was the difference. I mean, I can see the difference, but what did I do wrong there?

Comment: You had negation in `RewriteCond` using `!` and there is a small change in pattern also.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much. Now I have one question left. Is this the correct way to do this validation: If HTTP request (domainname), exists in database, nothing happens. But if it doesn't exist, a COOKIE will be set, and HTaccess will deny this request.

Comment: htaccess cannot query your database so that needs to happen in code like php.

Comment: That's right, so this is a way to go, right? How am I able to deny the whole request by the way? Now i'm just redirecting the user to google.com

Comment: From PHP code you can just use `header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden'); exit;` to block the access

Comment: Alright, and is there another way to avoid this request (each time requesting the domain from the DB)? Like a kind of whitelist for virtual hosts. I'm trying to achieve a shared hosting system. So that whenever a domainname is registered in the DB, the server allows the connection. Right now, each request is retrieving data from the DB, which isn't OOP at all.

Comment: Comments are not the right place to discuss a new question. You should accept this answer and post a new question then you will get much better answers.